# -canOpenURL: failed for URL: "fbauth2:/" - error: "The operation couldn’t be completed. (OSStatus error -10814.)" SWIFT 5 FBDSKCoreKit 5

Tags: ios, swift, facebook, facebook-login, swift5

I have seen a few similar threads and possible solutions, but they are all 1+ yrs old and I dont think relevant to updated versions.

I'm using swift 5, and FirebaseUI 8.4.2 which is compatible with FBSDKLoginKit (~> 5.0). (also using ios 12.2)

My info.plist includes fbauth2 and I've included App Transport Security Settings  --> allow arbitrary loads = YES which was added for ios 9.

In my appDelegate I have

```
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    FirebaseApp.configure()
    let db = Firestore.firestore()

    //facebook login
    //ApplicationDelegate.shared.application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)

    FBSDKCoreKit.ApplicationDelegate.shared.application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)

  return true
   }

  func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool {
      let handled = ApplicationDelegate.shared.application(app, open: url, options: options)

      return handled
  }
```

Feel like ive exhausted all solutions in other threads so if anyone has an updated workaround pls could you post below.

After clicking login button receive this message:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Did you add the correct url scheme for fb in `URL Types` section in `XCode project -> Info` tab.

[Xcode project Info tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mId7w.png)

You can verify that by checking `url.scheme` in `application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:])`.

Comment: The url scheme is definitely correct, but tried printing url.scheme in the application as above and it doesn't print. Should this be getting called?

Comment: It will be getting called when redirecting back from FB app after login.

Comment: Are you trying to login with a test user account or live fb account? To test with a live fb account, this app should be configured for that in the FB dveloper account dashboard.

Comment: user email and password from test user setup in FB developer acc